# Android group chat display only empty listview without old messages just new messages when user join group

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, chat, groupchat

ISo i have group chat in my app. I have "rooms" and button join "room", when user click join button all old messages appears on screen but I want to display only new ones, I'm using firebase list adapter for displaying...everything works fine but just don't know how to display empty list and only new messages, ty.

```
     btnJoin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            DatabaseReference db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("EventsUsers").child(uniqEventID);
            db.child(user.getUid()).setValue("");


        }
    });

   btnSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            DatabaseReference db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("EventsUsers").child(uniqEventID).child("Messages").push();
            db.setValue(new ChatMessage(ePlain.getText().toString(),user.getDisplayName()));
            ePlain.setText("");
            ePlain.requestFocus();

        }
    });
    private void displayChat() {
    btnSend.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    eventChat.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    FirebaseListAdapter<ChatMessage> adapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<ChatMessage>(EventDetails.this,ChatMessage.class,R.layout.one_chat_list,FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("EventsUsers").child(uniqEventID).child("Messages")) {
        @Override
        protected void populateView(View v, ChatMessage model, int position) {
            TextView messageTextm,messageUser,messageTime;
            messageTextm = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.chatMessage);
            messageUser = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.chatUserName);
            messageTime = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.message_time);

            messageTextm.setText(model.getMessageText());
            messageUser.setText(model.getMessageUser());
            messageTime.setText(DateFormat.format("dd-MM-yyyy (HH:mm)", model.getMessageTime()));

        }
    };
    eventChat.setAdapter(adapter);

}
    DatabaseReference check = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("EventsUsers").child(uniqEventID);
            check.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    if(dataSnapshot.hasChild(user.getUid())){
                        displayChat();
                    }
                }
```

So when user clicks join button listview with messages displays with all old messages before he joined...and sorry for not uploading any code I am new here, tell me if you need something else of my code
This is my database structure https://ibb.co/d47D9v

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. When asking a question we ask that you post your code and what you have tried where applicable. This will get you the best help. You may find this article helpful:https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to keep track of time in firebase.  First you need to keep track of when the messages are posted, second, you need to keep track of when a user joins the room.  Then, when you query the messages you can

`sortBy('time').startAt(timeUserJoined)`

**EDIT**
on your button join onClick you have

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("EventsUsers")
    .child(uniqEventID).child(user.getUid()).setValue("");
```

set the value to the current time instead of just adding an empty node as a flag.

Then, when you add a message you need to add the time it was added as well.  So just add this to the class you already made

```
db.setValue(new ChatMessage(ePlain.getText().toString(),
    user.getDisplayName()), System.currentTimeMillis());
```

Finally, in your adapter, your reference should be more like

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("EventsUsers")
    .child(uniqEventID).child("Messages")
    .orderBy("time").beginAt(timeUserJoined)
```

timeUserJoined is the value the user's id as a key from above

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("EventsUsers").child(uniqEventID)
    .setSingleValueListener( result-> timeUserJoing = result.value)
```

this is not perfect code but i think you get the point